# Apps Script Advanced Services Drive SDK Drive.File.get(fileId) returns poorly formatted objects

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

In Google Apps Script I have enabled the Advanced Drive Service.

When using this to get a file by id, the response is very odd. It looks like an object, but is not parseable.

Ex.

```
Drive.Files.get('1_abRfYS-CZvKorjrWutUpRZxvIO_otTkpaZJ4R-KkwE');
```

If I put this in the Logger I get:

```
{parents=[{id=0BzWxtgoG46sIc0YtZlZaTGhsVjA, parentLink=https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0BzWxtgoG46sIc0YtZlZaTGhsVjA, isRoot=false, selfLink=https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1_abRfYS-CZvKorjrWutUpRZxvIO_otTkpaZJ4R-KkwE/parents/0BzWxtgoG46sIc0YtZlZaTGhsVjA, kind=drive#parentReference}], etag="sIP8ArR2PAy9qIx8FYkTpbHmKik/MTQwMTIzNzEzOTg4Mw", embedLink=https://docs.google.com/a/thinksolid.com/spreadsheets/d/1_abRfYS-CZvKorjrWutUpRZxvIO_otTkpaZJ4R-KkwE/htmlembed, userPermission={id=me, etag="sIP8ArR2PAy9qIx8FYkTpbHmKik/w4QxcIs4En-Mb76iujO61dBDECI", role=owner, selfLink=https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1_abRfYS-CZvKorjrWutUpRZxvIO_otTkpaZJ4R-KkwE/permissions/me, type=user, kind=drive#permission}, lastViewedByMeDate=2014-05-28T00:41:59.324Z, kind=drive#file, exportLinks={application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=1_abRfYS-CZvKorjrWutUpRZxvIO_otTkpaZJ4R-KkwE&exportFormat=xlsx, application/pdf=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=1_abRfYS-CZvKorjrWutUpRZxvIO_otTkpaZJ4R-KkwE&exportFormat=pdf}, lastModifyingUser={isAuthenticatedUser=true, emailAddress=greg.larrenaga@thinksolid.com, permissionId=06635965192609567538, displayName=Greg Larrenaga, kind=drive#user}, version=8992, id=1_abRfYS-CZvKorjrWutUpRZxvIO_otTkpaZJ4R-KkwE, lastModifyingUserName=Greg Larrenaga, alternateLink=https://docs.google.com/a/thinksolid.com/spreadsheets/d/1_abRfYS-CZvKorjrWutUpRZxvIO_otTkpaZJ4R-KkwE/edit?usp=drivesdk, title=ThePlanningGuide - 2014-05-28T00:32:19Z, createdDate=2014-05-28T00:32:20.162Z, mimeType=application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet, shared=true, appDataContents=false, iconLink=https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_11_spreadsheet_list.png, writersCanShare=true, modifiedByMeDate=2014-05-28T00:32:19.883Z, labels={trashed=false, starred=false, hidden=false, restricted=false, viewed=true}, quotaBytesUsed=0, selfLink=https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1_abRfYS-CZvKorjrWutUpRZxvIO_otTkpaZJ4R-KkwE, markedViewedByMeDate=2014-05-28T00:41:58.962Z, ownerNames=[Greg Larrenaga], modifiedDate=2014-05-28T00:32:19.883Z, editable=true, copyable=true, thumbnailLink=https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/d_Pbk26bwz2bG0Z4UlN_GQBWlSG_MFi4j18KPqMVPBCgUA6XO9TurbqkBqnSpPgF-PC1xYHbNs2MEgSEbg=s220, owners=[{isAuthenticatedUser=true, emailAddress=greg.larrenaga@thinksolid.com, permissionId=06635965192609567538, displayName=Greg Larrenaga, kind=drive#user}]}
```

You should notice the `=` signs instead of the usual `:` to indicate key value pairs.
I am unsure how to get this into a useable format.

The expected response would be a useable javascript object, or valid JSON that I can parse.

I need to dive into the `exportLinks` object inside the return.

If this is a bug I will gladly file it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can just dive into those objects as if they were POJO's.

```
file.exportLinks['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet']
```

Comment: Unlike our Default Services, Advanced Services accept and return regular JavaScript POJOs.